# CakePHP pagination maximum limit not working

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using cakephp 2.x. I am unable to set maximum limit of my record.

Please check my code:

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class BroadcastsController extends AppController {
   public $components = array('Paginator');

   public function broadcast(){           
         $this->Paginator->settings = array('limit' => 10,  'order' => array('Broadcast.no_of_user' => 'DESC'), 'group' => 'Broadcast.broadcaster_id');
         $popularRooms = $this->Paginator->paginate('Broadcast');
         pr($popularRooms); //fetch 200 records
         $this->set('popularRooms', $popularRooms);
   }
}
```

Above `pr($popularRooms);` I am getting 200 records but I want first 50 records and per page showing 10 records. I was using `'maxLimit'=>50` but this code same as `'limit'=>50`. Please help me.

Comment: Where you declared  of  `Paginator` component &  `PaginatorHelper `? please share of your code properly.

Comment: hi @u2460470 i have updated my question. Please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case, you can use the 'extras' array in your paginator setting

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array('limit' => 10, 'max_record'=>50, 'order' => array('Broadcast.no_of_user' => 'DESC'), 'group' => 'Broadcast.broadcaster_id');
```

in your model or AppModel overiding the paginateCount function

```
class Broadcast extends AppModel { 
function paginateCount($conditions, $recursive, $extra) {
    $param = array_merge(compact('conditions', 'recursive'), $extra);
    $count = $this->find('count', $param);
    if (!empty($extra['max_record']) && $count > $extra['max_records']) {
      $count = $extra['max_record'];
    }
    return $count;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks sanjib for your nice answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

By default CakePHP limits the maximum number of rows that can be fetched to 100.You can adjust it as part of the pagination options like below

```
public $paginate = array(
    // other keys here.
    'maxLimit' => 10
);
```

For you code set the maxLimit like this

```
 $this->Paginator->settings = array('limit' => 10,'maxLimit'=>50,'order' => array('Broadcast.no_of_user' => 'DESC'), 'group' => 'Broadcast.broadcaster_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function list_posts() {
    $settings = array(
       'limit' => 25, // here
       'order' => array(
          'Post.title' => 'asc'
        )
    );
    $this->Paginator->settings = $this->settings;
    // similar to findAll(), but fetches paged results
    $data = $this->Paginator->paginate('Posts');
    $this->set('data', $data);
```

}

Comment: In above my code i am getting 200 records i need 50 record with 10 per page.

Comment: try adding this prop in 'maxLimit' => 50

Comment: 'maxLimit'=>50 this is same as 'limit'=>50

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't have to have $this->Paginator->settings =.

```
public function list_posts() {
$settings = array(
   'limit' => 25, // here
   'order' => array(
      'Post.title' => 'asc'
    )
);
// similar to findAll(), but fetches paged results
$data = $this->Paginator->paginate('Posts');
$this->set('data', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set maxLimit first in your paginator settings before limit like this:

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
 'maxLimit' => 50,  
 'limit' => 10,  
 'order' => array('Broadcast.no_of_user' => 'DESC'), 
 'group' => 'Broadcast.broadcaster_id'
);
```

Only setting one of them logically does not change anything.

Comment: `'maxLimit'=>50` it seems same as `'limit'=>50` i can't see the deference.